# Unexpected token ')' in E:\portfolio\views\home.ejs while compiling ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, viewengine

I got an error while looping the array through forEach loop in ejs file of express js. According to my research, in the ejs file `forEach` loop is not working. Please check the error and the message below:

`Error`

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' in E:\portfolio\views\home.ejs while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at Template.compile (E:\portfolio\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:673:12)
    at Object.compile (E:\portfolio\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:398:16)
    at handleCache (E:\portfolio\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:235:18)
    at tryHandleCache (E:\portfolio\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:274:16)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (E:\portfolio\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
    at View.render (E:\portfolio\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (E:\portfolio\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (E:\portfolio\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (E:\portfolio\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1017:7)
```

`The code`

`/index.js` from the root directory:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const PostsRoute = require("./routers/posts");
const PageRoute = require("./routers/pageRoutes/routes");
const app = express();


**MongoDB connection Here**


app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended : false}));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './views'))
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.use("/css" , express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'views/css')));
app.use("/js" , express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'views/js')));


app.use("/api",PostsRoute);
app.use("/",PageRoute);

app.listen(process.env.PORT,() => {
    console.log(`Your port is running`);
});
```

`routers/post.js` from the root directory:

```
const express = require("express");
const PostsRoute = require("express").Router();
const PostModel = require("../models/post");

PostsRoute.get("/posts", async (req, res) => {
  const posts = await PostModel.find();
  try {
    const result = await PostModel.find();
    res.status(200).send(result);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});


module.exports = PostsRoute;
```

`routers/pageRoutes/routes.js` from the root directory:

```
const PageRoute = require("express").Router();
const axios = require("axios");

PageRoute.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios("http://localhost:5000/api/posts");
    res.render("home" , { posts : response.data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
});


module.exports = PageRoute;
```

Now finally the ejs file is here `views/home.ejs` from the root directory

```
<%- include("partials/header.ejs"); %>
<div class="posts container">
  <div class="row">
    <%- posts.forEach(post => { %> 
       <%- include("Postcard.ejs"); %>
    <%- }); %>
  </div>
</div>
<%- include("partials/footer.ejs"); %>
```

Comment: Point to be noted, "I have only the simple Html in Postcard.ejs" file.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change this:

```
<%- posts.forEach(post => { %> 
   <%- include("Postcard.ejs"); %>
<%- }); %>
```

to this:

```
<% posts.forEach(post => { %> 
   <%- include("Postcard.ejs"); %>
<% }); %>
```

just needed to remove the -

this is from ejs docs:

```
<ul>
  <% users.forEach(function(user){ %>
    <%- include('user/show', {user: user}); %>
  <% }); %>
</ul>
```

[ejs docs](https://ejs.co/) , scroll down to Includes title.

Comment: Does not work but infect browser has printed it as it is with this error :    posts.forEach is not a function
    at eval ("E:\\portfolio\\views\\home.ejs":12:14)

Comment: Now you are facing different issue. seems like posts is not an array. can you console log the response.data before rendering the home page? just to make sure.

Comment: Yes i have tried it in the routers/pageRoutes/routes.js file before sending the response it shows all the data to be displayed perfectly!! i don't think the error is in that file because i have also tried to print `posts[0].key` and `posts[1].key` and that is displaying the result. Most likely to have the issue with loop. Let me tell you one thing more i also have tried to use `for loop` but it is also not working.

Comment: This is weird. it should loop through the array. its hard to debug such an issue without being able to reproduce the error..

Comment: OMG!! There might be another suggestion!!!

Answer (score -1):

Unexcepted token error means, probably you can wrong use symbols like used two less than symbols << or you can not use on html "<" you must use html entity (&ls;). Just focus on symbols.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).